# Converting multi-line script output to dictionary using regex

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

I got the following script output:

```
***************************************************
[g4u2680c]: searching for domains
---------------------------------------------------
host =   g4u2680c.houston.example.com
         ipaddr = [16.208.16.72]
         VLAN   = [352]
         Gateway= [16.208.16.1]
         Subnet = [255.255.248.0]
         Subnet = [255.255.248.0]
         Cluster= [g4u2679c g4u2680c g9u1484c g9u1485c]

host =   g4u2680c.houston.example.com
         ipaddr = [16.208.16.72]
         VLAN   = [352]
         Gateway= [16.208.16.1]
         Subnet = [255.255.248.0]
         Subnet = [255.255.248.0]
         Cluster= [g4u2679c g4u2680c g9u1484c g9u1485c]

* script completed Mon Jun 15 06:13:14 UTC 2015 **
* sleeping 30 to avoid DOS on dns via a loop **
```

---

I need to extract the 2 host list into a dictionary, with out the brackets.

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/env python

import re

text="""*************************************************** 
[g4u2680c]: searching for domains
---------------------------------------------------
host =   g4u2680c.houston.example.com
         ipaddr = [16.208.16.72]
         VLAN   = [352]
         Gateway= [16.208.16.1]
         Subnet = [255.255.248.0]
         Subnet = [255.255.248.0]
         Cluster= [g4u2679c g4u2680c g9u1484c g9u1485c]

host =   g4u2680c.houston.example.com
         ipaddr = [16.208.16.72]
         VLAN   = [352]
         Gateway= [16.208.16.1]
         Subnet = [255.255.248.0]
         Subnet = [255.255.248.0]
         Cluster= [g4u2679c g4u2680c g9u1484c g9u1485c]

* script completed Mon Jun 15 06:13:14 UTC 2015 **
* sleeping 30 to avoid DOS on dns via a loop **
***************************************************
"""

seq = re.compile(r"host.+?\n\n",re.DOTALL)

a=seq.findall(text)

matches = re.findall(r'\w.+=.+', a[0])

matches = [m.split('=', 1) for m in matches]

matches = [ [m[0].strip().lower(), m[1].strip().lower()] for m in matches]

#should have function with regular expression to remove bracket here

d = dict(matches)

print d
```

What I got so far for the first host:

```
{'subnet': '[255.255.248.0]', 'vlan': '[352]', 'ipaddr': '[16.208.16.72]', 'cluster': '[g4u2679c g4u2680c g9u1484c g9u1485c]', 'host': 'g4u2680c.houston.example.com', 'gateway': '[16.208.16.1]'}
```

I need help to find the regex to remove the bracket as the value in the dictionary contain data with and without bracket.

Or if there is a better and simpler way to transform the original script output into dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use:** `(\w+)\s*=\s*\[?([^\n\]]+)\]?`

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/mU9xJ5/1)

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'(\w+)\s*=\s*\[?([^\n\]]+)\]?', re.MULTILINE)
test_str = u"host =   g4u2680c.houston.example.com\n         ipaddr = [16.208.16.72]\n         VLAN   = [352]\n         Gateway= [16.208.16.1]\n         Subnet = [255.255.248.0]\n         Subnet = [255.255.248.0]\n         Cluster= [g4u2679c g4u2680c g9u1484c g9u1485c]\n\nhost =   g4u2680c.houston.example.com\n         ipaddr = [16.208.16.72]\n         VLAN   = [352]\n         Gateway= [16.208.16.1]\n         Subnet = [255.255.248.0]\n         Subnet = [255.255.248.0]\n         Cluster= [g4u2679c g4u2680c g9u1484c g9u1485c]\n"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

Comment: Ok, thanks too. If that helps you, then accept this ans.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `re.findall` and `dict` :

```
>>> dict([(i,j.strip('[]')) for i,j in re.findall(r'(\w+)\s*=\s*(.+)',text)])
{'Subnet': '255.255.248.0', 'VLAN': '352', 'ipaddr': '16.208.16.72', 'Cluster': 'g4u2679c g4u2680c g9u1484c g9u1485c', 'host': 'g4u2680c.houston.example.com', 'Gateway': '16.208.16.1'}
```

And about the brackets you can remove them by `str.strip` method.

Comment: Your solution did not match the hostname, as the hostname did not have bracket.

Comment: @SharuzzamanAhmatRaslan If you want the host name too you can loop over the `re.findall()` and remove the brackets with `str.strip`

Comment: I wish I can accept more than one answer, as your answer is interesting too

Answer (score 0):

You can try out this.

```
matches = [m.replace('[','').replace(']','').split('=', 1) for m in matches]
```